# Print all possible combinations of r elements using string

Tags: java, string, recursion, recursive-backtracking

[image]

I was trying to solve this question using this simple recursive and backtracking approach.My idea was this:

**code**

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{

    static void generate(String s, String ans , int r)
    {
        if(ans.length()-1==r)
        {
            System.out.print(ans);

            return;
        }

        char ch=s.charAt(0);

        for(int i=1;i<=s.length()-1;i++)
        {
            String ros=s.substring(i);

            generate(ros,ans+ch,r);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a="123";
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int r=sc.nextInt();
        String ans=" ";
        generate(a,ans,r);
    }
}
```

**my output with string 123** : 12

Required output : 12 13 23

I hope my recursive tree is right but I am not able to code it. My code seems to have some major issues

Comment: By 'combinations', do you specifically mean 'of length 2'?  'Cause there's '', '1', '2', '3', '123' which are combinations of those not included in your intended output.

Comment: Yes, I mean all the combinations of length 2

Comment: And to check, does input with repeated characters count as different combinations.  For example, for '111' as input, would you want '11', '11', '11' as output, or simply '11'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is different code using ArrayList but using same logic as **Nathan Drake** :

import java.util.*;

public class Main

{

    public static void PrintAllCombinations(int[] arr, int r) {
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
PrintAllCombinationsUtils(arr, r, list, 0);
}

private static void PrintAllCombinationsUtils(int[] arr, int r, List<Integer> list, int start) {

if (list.size() >= r) {

System.out.println(list);

return;

}

for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {

list.add(arr[i]);

PrintAllCombinationsUtils(arr, r, list, i + 1);

list.remove(list.size() - 1);

}

}

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int r=sc.nextInt();

        int arr[]=new int[5];

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)

        {
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }

        PrintAllCombinations( arr, r);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if my understanding is right, input "12345" and 3, output should be

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

then this is my program

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main{
    static void generate(String s, int r){
        recursiveGenerate(s, new LinkedList<>(), r, 0);
    }

    static void recursiveGenerate(String s, Deque<Character> cache, int len, int start){
        if(cache.size() == len){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cache.toArray()));
        }
        else{
            for(int i = start; i < s.length(); i++){
                cache.addLast(s.charAt(i));
                recursiveGenerate(s, cache, len, i + 1);
                cache.removeLast();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "12345";
        int r = 3;
        generate(a, r);
    }
}
```